# What is the meaning of column integrated fluxes?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am solving an equation where one term $\bar{P}$ is given and is called the integrated column flux. In the equation, the term $P$ is the precipitation. I am doing this on the discrete domain.

Anyone please let me know the meaning of $\bar{P}$ here?

Is it the average value of $P$ corresponding to the each column?

The following is the text given in the paper.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know either one, but is it "column integrated flux" or "integrated column flux"?

Comment: @LSpice it is given as column integrated flux.

Comment: I [see](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429232/what-is-the-meaning-of-column-integrated-fluxes#comment1104244_429232).  Then I would recommend also using that term in the body of your post.  It will also help a lot if you give context:  where does the equation arise?

Comment: @LSpice I added the text and equation (3) given in the paper in the post.

Comment: You have posted some pages from a paper.  What is the paper?